# Laravel foreach loop not outputting to form

Tags: php, forms, laravel

Here is a form from my Laravel 5 project:

```
  <form class="form-group" action="/counselors/{{ $counselor->id }}/badges/add" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
        @foreach($badges as $badge)
            <div class="input-group">
              <span class="input-group-addon">
                <input type="checkbox" style="float: left" value="{{ $badge->id }}">&nbsp;{{ $badge->name }}
              </span>
            </div>
        @endforeach
        <br>
        <input type="submit" class="form-control btn btn-primary" name="submit" value="Submit"><hr>
        <input type="button" class="form-control btn btn-danger" name="cancel" value="Cancel" onClick="location='/counselors'">
    </form>
```

The $badges is a collection of badges from a database.  They all iterate and display properly, but when i look at the request data with

```
$request->all()
```

it returns:

```
{"_token":"5E4csIJU4YVVQZSoPG1EmpfHfjNjYcRwuOoreCcE","submit":"Submit"}
```

It doesn't include the checkbox data from the loop.  Is this incorrect?  What's the best way to do this? There are 160 items in the $badges collection.

I'm pretty new so please go easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put **name** attribute to the input checkbox and giv it a value

```
<input type="checkbox" name="check-{{ $badge->id }}" style="float: left" value="{{ $badge->id }}">&nbsp;{{ $badge->name }}
```

Note :
here i use the name "check-" and the id of the badge to get defferent name for each checkbox

Comment: Wow, I feel very dumb now.  Thank you for the help, that was the problem.